# Docker Installation process can't complete due to file being in use elsewhere

Tags: windows, docker, download

While trying to reinstall Docker for Windows, I am facing the following error -

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program
>   Files\Docker\Docker\resources\docker-for-win.iso' because it is being
>   used by another process.

Is there any resolution to this issue?

Comment: Use **Ctrl+Alt+Del** on Windows to see the processes that are using your iso file, and kill them, so the file will be released.

Comment: Problem is there is nothing that overtly makes it clear where else this iso file is being used. And I am not very much familiar with such a phenomenon?

Comment: iso is an image, so definitely your image is used - you can just reboot your machine, uninstall docker from control panel or get a new installation from here https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#about-windows-containers

Comment: I had to shutdown server and delete .iso files and then remove server. It worked for me like that.

Answer (score 28):

My way is:

1. open **Task Manager**
2. Select tab **Details**
3. Click to the title of the table. Click mouse right to open context menu. Select **select columns**
4. Select to show the **command line column**
5. Search the process occupied that file
6. Kill the process
   It's okay with me.
   [image]

Answer (score 14):

Open Hyper-V Manager => select your system name => select DockerDesktop VM under Virtual Machines => then click on Remove Server => Then restart your system.

Your ready to setup docker.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It did not work for me. After a restart, the server is recreated and locking the file again. 
However, stopping it without restarting the system was enough to release the locked file. Relaunch Docker would be it.

Comment: The caption for Remove Server says it "Removes the server from the MMC snap-in", so it's merely a visual thing.  It removes "your system name" from view and doesn't do anything to the virtual machine you're told us to select.  I got mine to run by right-clicking DockerDesktopVM and selecting "Turn Off.." followed by "Delete...".

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to be quick, otherwise the VM restarted and locked the file again.

Comment: Instead of removing the server, I just shut it down and the installation finished fine after that

Answer (score 8):

[image]

I had the same problem. Have tried a lot of things. Thing which really helped me was this:
Go to resource manager. CPU TAB. Associated handlers section. Search. Write docker. Find all files which holds your resource file and stop that process with right click.
Process which holds your docker file.
After start again installation... :)
My installation result
[image]

Comment: a great guidance

Answer (score 2):

There could be a service running with display name "Docker Desktop Service". You need to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I ran into same issue and I solved by disabling it from my task manager.
For that open Task Manager(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>) the go to services tab select open services find docker desktop service from it right click and select properties . change startup type to disable and press apply now u can delete docker folder from program files and reinstall docker .

Answer (score 0):

Running the executable with Admin privileges solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is
Task Manager > Services, find the running docker processor, stop it and then reinstall the docker package.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the docker service on windows. It worked for me